# Rails - Associating an object with multiple accounts and then modifying the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Credits that belong to Accounts, but are traded back and forth between accounts. I need to be able to keep track of which account a credit currently belongs to, and which account originally created the credit. Currently I have an association like this:

```
    class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :original_owner, :foreign_key => "account_id", :class_name => "Account"
      belongs_to :account, :class_name => Account
    end
```

Now in the rails console, I can set Credit.account.id = 3, and Credit.original_owner.id = 4, but that just changes the "Account id" and doesn't actually change the association. If I set Credit.account = Account.find(3), that works, but I can't set Credit.original_owner to Account.find(4). It indicates that it saved correctly, but it doesn't. It only changes with Credit.account. Every time I change the account, it changes the original_owner along with it.

How can I set up my association so that my Credits belong to an account but still keep track of their original account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the foreign key for the `original_owner` association to `account_id` because that's the foreign key for the `account` association. You need to have a distinctly named foreign key for each association. (i.e. `original_owner_id`)

`@credit.account.id = 3` and `@credit.original_owner.id = 4` are not correct either. You're attempting to change the `id` of the associated objects. I assume what you're trying to is modify the association, which is done with `@credit.account_id = 3` (using the foreign key), or, as you pointed out `@credit.account = Account.find(3)` also works if you want to work with objects.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I changed the foreign key to original_owner_id and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new column to your model and map `foreign_key` to that column.